# Accurate signal reconstruction

Tags: signal, frequency, oscilloscope, dsp, sampling

While reading through [this](https://www.tek.com/document/online/primer/xyzs-scopes/ch3/evaluating-oscilloscopes) page I came across following info:

"For accurate reconstruction using sin (x)/x interpolation, your oscilloscope should have a sample rate at least 2.5 times the highest frequency component of your signal. Using linear interpolation, the sample rate should be at least 10 times the highest frequency signal component."

I could not understand why is there so big difference in sampling rate if the interpolation type is changed from one to the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*sin(x)/x* or *sinc* is the function of the ideal low pass filter.

Your scope has a sharp cutoff at f/2 (at least you are prentending that), and using the ideal low pass filter for interpolation then gives you a result better matching the characteristics of that ideal scope than linear interpolation.

Or in short: with sinc, you at least don't see such artifacts as straight lines where there should be distortion.

Comment: I mean what is so special about the sinc function compared to a line that you get very good results in interpolation with lower sampling rate?

Comment: Because **the sinc function is the ideal low-pass filter**, and because of the Nyquist-Shannon sampling theorem.  The answer to "why is that" is that you need to trust us, or learn signal processing, which is a book-length subject.

Comment: @alt-rose: Consider you have two sampling points, one of 1V at 90° phase and one of -1V at 270° phase. If you connected them with straight lines, you see a triangle wave. But an ideal scope had to show a sine wave. That's what the sinc interpolation does.